# Missing close quote of string. Verilog

Tags: verilog, iverilog

im creating a 16 bit ripple carry adder using verilog and simulate it using icarus but below i just have the test bench file attachment. Im new to learning verilog and i have this error code ("Missing close quote of string") that i cant seem to figure out. I apologize if this seems like an easy fix as i am probably overlooking something simple.

this is the section of the code I am getting an error code on. line 4 of the section I am getting the error "Missing close quote of string". I am also getting the error "malformed statement" on line 9 of the section below.

```
initial
$monitor("time= ", 
$time, 
"A=%b, 
B=&b, 
Cin=%b
: Sum= %b,
Cout=%cout",
a,b,cin,sum,cout);
endmodule
```

Below i added the full test bench code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module ripple_carry_16_bit_tb;
wire [15:0] sum;//output
wire cout;//output
reg [15:0] a,b;//input
reg cin;//input

ripple_carry_16_bit uut(
.a(a),
.b(b),
.cin(cin),
.sum(sum),
.cout(cout));

initial begin
$display($time, " << Starting the Simulation >>");
     a=0; b=0; cin=0;
#100 a= 16'b0000000000011111; b=16'b000000000001100; cin=1'b0;
#10 a= 16'b0000000000011111; b=16'b000000000001100; cin=1'b0;
#10 a= 16'b1100011000011111; b=16'b000000110001100; cin=1'b1;
#10 a= 16'b1111111111111111; b=16'b000000000000000; cin=1'b1;
end

initial
$monitor("time= ", 
$time, 
"A=%b, 
B=&b, 
Cin=%b
: Sum= %b,
Cout=%cout",
a,b,cin,sum,cout);
endmodule
```

Thank you in advance to anyone that can guide me in the right direction.

tried adding the quote to the end of the line but that just gets me more errors.

Answer (score 0):

You may break a quoted string with '\'. Try this:

```
initial
  $monitor("time= ", 
  $time, 
  "A=%b, \
  B=&b, \
  Cin=%b \
  : Sum= %b, \
  Cout=%cout",
  a,b,cin,sum,cout);
endmodule
```